# what kind of effects were used for that visual particle swirl effect?

Tags: flash, effects, particles, particle-system, visual-effects

one of my client asks me such effect for his interactive presentation :

http://vimeo.com/36466564

Can someone give me some tips about what kind of effects (particles, swirl, displacements) were done for that ?

(It must be done using FLASH )

Comment: he said he made it using http://www.openframeworks.cc/ meaning it's C++.

Comment: I need some clues about how to duplicate these effects.
Not what langage he used (I need to use Flash)

regards

Comment: ah sorry... looking at the part where he drags the particles off with his hand, it kinda looks like some sort of particle swarming / flocking.

I don't know how much of this you can replicate in flash :/

Answer (score 0):

The simulation of such effects with animation is difficult and takes a lot of time.

To know more particle effect visit to :

http://www.csit.parkland.edu/~dbock/Class/csc233/Lecture/ParticlesIntroduction.html
http://platinumplatypus.com